# Download to CSV in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I'm building a search function for my company, as part of this the management team can generate a search with a search form I made, this is a view that sends the various terms to a controller method `execute_search`, this gets the results from the databases via my `Search_model` and outputs them in the view. As part of this I have a "Download" button that I want to export the results to CSV. Ive made a controller function:

```
function convert_to_csv($results)
{

    /** open raw memory as file, no need for temp files */
    $temp_memory = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    /** loop through array  */
    foreach ($results as $line) {
        /** default php csv handler **/
        fputcsv($temp_memory, $line);
    }
    /** rewrind the "file" with the csv lines **/
    fseek($temp_memory, 0);
    /** modify header to be downloadable csv file **/
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="Statistics_system_report.csv";');
    /** Send file to browser for download */
    fpassthru($temp_memory);
}
```

I'm getting errors in my downloades CSV file saying that `$results` is undefined.

My question is what would be the best way to send the results to this function but only execute the function if my user clicks the download button? I've tried this:
`$this->convert_to_csv($results);`
as part of my `execute_search` function but this then downloads it every time a search is executed, any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Well have you checked what `$result` is before you make the call to the method i.e. this call `$this->convert_to_csv($results);`

Comment: yes, its a multidimensional array from the model as a result of `$query->get()->result_array();`

Answer (score 1):

Optimal solution will be PHPExcel library, so go for it instead of solve this issue by patching ;)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into this library as it could be a useful resource ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I solved this issue, there is probably a better way, but heres what I did:

in the controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session'); // Load sessions
    /* ..... */
}
```

Then in my `execute_search` function I set the flashdata:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('results', $results);
```

Then in my export function:

```
function convert_to_csv()
{
    /** retrieve the search results */
    $results = $this->session->flashdata('results');
    /* ....... */
}
```

The issue with this is that if I download it more than once, I get a PHP error in the CSV file as the flashdata is cleared

If anyone has a better solution i'm all ears. Cheers

**/* EDIT */**
To avoid any errors, I reset the flashdata at the end of my `export_to_csv` function like so:

```
 // Reset the results in flash data
 $this->session->set_flashdata('results', $results);
```

Again, not good practise but solves my issue for now :)